# Get parameters types of a constructor as tuple

Tags: typescript, constructor

I have this code:

```js
class Route {
  constructor(
    public method: 'get' | 'post' | 'update' | 'delete',
    public path: string,
    public handler: () => string,
  ) {}
}

class Router {
  constructor(private routes: (Route | Parameters<typeof Route.constructor>)[] = []) {}
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to make `Router` accept an array of either `Route` object or just an array of arguments to construct the `Route`s, like this:

```js
const router = new Router([
  new Route('get', '/', () => 'Hello, world!'),

  // or
  ['get', '/', () => 'Hello, world!'],
]);
```

I know `Parameters` could be used to get the parameters of a functions as tuple, and it works for all functions and methods normally, but when I try to use it with any constructors, the compiler gives this error:
`Type 'Function' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any) => any'.`

I've been googling it but haven't been able to find any previous questions that satisfy my case.

So, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `ConstructorParameters` directly on `typeof Route`

```
class Route {
    constructor(
        public method: 'get' | 'post' | 'update' | 'delete',
        public path: string,
        public handler: () => string,
    ) { }
}

class Router {
    constructor(private routes: (Route | ConstructorParameters<typeof Route>)[] = []) { }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Works like a charm!! Thank you very much!

Comment: This is great, how did you get to learn this? I can not find it on the Typescript documentation website...

Comment: @Titulum following the github repo, reading all the realeas notes and relevant PRs. Answering question on stackoverflow :-)

Comment: Hmmm, I think it's too bad that the documentation is not complete then...