# TypeScript dynamic constructor using object with classes as properties

Tags: typescript

I can dynamically select a class and construct an instance of it like so:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(public val: number) {}
}

class Bar {
  constructor(public val: string) {}
}

const classMap = {
  foo: Foo,
  bar: Bar,
} as const;

const foo = new classMap["foo"](10);
```

And type inference seems to work well - the constructor function expects a number and `foo` is correctly typed as `Foo`.

However, if I try to use `classMap` itself as a type, I get weird behavior where the properties get typed as `typeof Foo` and `typeof Bar` instead of `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
type ClassMap = typeof classMap // { readonly foo: typeof Foo, readonly bar: typeof Bar};
type InferredFoo = ClassMap["foo"] // typeof Foo;
type ShouldBeNumber = InferredFoo["val"] // Error: Property 'val' does not exist on type 'typeof Foo';
```

Is there some way to fix this? I only want to be able to select the class dynamically at compile time, not runtime.

Btw with other property types, this does not happen:

```
const classMap = {
  foo: Foo,
  bar: Bar,
  baz: 10,
} as const // { foo: typeof Foo, bar: typeof Bar, baz: 10 };
```

Comment: Is this a confusion about the difference between a constructor type and its instance type?  `typeof Foo` is the type of the value `Foo`, the class constructor.  If you want the instance type you need something like `type ShouldBeNumber = InstanceType<InferredFoo>["val"]` instead.   But this has nothing much to do with being "dynamic".  Maybe you could [edit] the question to focus on getting the type of an instance from the type of its constructor?

Comment: At least strongly related: [*Get parameters types of a constructor as tuple*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56599419/get-parameters-types-of-a-constructor-as-tuple)

Comment: Oh right, thanks, yeah I got the constructor and the class type confused

Answer (score 1):

`val` isn't a *property* of the `Foo` constructor, it's the constructor's first parameter. To get the type of that parameter from `InferredFoo`, you'd use the tuple from [`ConstructorParameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype):

```
type ShouldBeNumber = ConstructorParameters<InferredFoo>[0];
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1rHgOwgFwCcBXYPeAgCgAciAjEAS2GgDcwQAuabIgW1oCmBAJQoAvqgmpQkGACEwBFOkw58xUuWp1GzNp2jqG2AOajkEqVlx5M4KAFkwVaAF5lGAGaIuCeABoVWkUuBQJAsWhIVRsAblRUPABPKgFoAGF7CCcXd2TU+E87WRzoAHoylGgCATAAExwQJOhveC58gUK4RH9q2obsJuhggnaUzqKwsXiO6ABJbE8hGrq-NwysnIBtACJWnYBdcsqOrr8Z8egAZQALeCIQOrkBADk+QSV3dLVCEjICAAKijAvAEeCEEAAPAslgQVn4AHxbAAMB1iQA)